# Loop through SQL columns Dynamically

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to update table1 from a copy, table2 given a list of columns.

How do I write a sql command to dynamically update all columns in table1 from table2 given a list of column names?.

I'm trying to avoid hardcoding column1, column2 in the sql query.

```
column_names = ['column1', 'column2'] 
# Want to make query below work automatically
# if I add another column name to `column_names`
sql_cmd = ("""
        UPDATE table1
        SET 
        table1.column1 = table2.column1,
        table1.column2 = table2.column2
        FROM table2
        WHERE table1.id = table2.id""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this option:

```
column_names = ['column1', 'column2']

sql_cmd = (""" UPDATE table1 SET table1.{} = table2.{}, 
                                 table1.{} = table2.{}
                FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id""").format(column_names[0], column_names[0], column_names[1], column_names[1])

print(sql_cmd)
```

**Sample Jinja2 Code using Macro:**

```
{% macro macro_join_condition(tab_prefix_1, tab_prefix_2, columns) %}
  {% for col in columns %}
    {% if loop.first %}
      {{ tab_prefix_1 }}{{ col }} = {{ tab_prefix_2 }}{{ col }}
    {% else %}
      and {{ tab_prefix_1 }}{{ col }} = {{ tab_prefix_2 }}{{ col }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

select *
from source_data sd right join target_data td on {{ macro_join_condition('td.','sd.', params.primaryKeyList) }}
```

Comment: Hi Soumendra, Thanks for that! Great work. How would we do it for variable length number of columns? Thanks!

Comment: You can use jinja2 to make it dynamic !

Comment: Hi Soumendra, can you give an updated example. I dont know how to code that.

Comment: Added a document link for reference: `https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-approach-to-templated-sql-queries-in-python-adc4f0dc511`

Comment: I feel there is another way or other ways that are simpler using SQL or python but its ok, thanks.